# Query property in keyless nested object

Tags: php, mongodb

I have data that is structured like so:

```
parent: [
    {
        val1: 'some data',
        val2: 'some data'
    },
    {
        val1: 'some data',
        val2: 'some data
    }
]
```

If I want to query the property 'val1' in all nested objects in the 'parent' array, is there a concise way of doing that even though the objects don't have a key?

Edit: Expanding the question a bit.

Basically, I want to be able to check values against val1 in my actual query rather than get every row of my database and then loop through them all with PHP.

I won't know the number of objects in the array, so I can't directly query them, i.e. $collection->find(array('parent[0]' => 'some data')). I'd like to be able to do the equivalent to "find all rows that have an object where the property val1 is set to ____ contained in the 'parent' array.

Comment: `foreach ($var->parent as $obj) print $obj->val1;` ?

Comment: yes, they have a key. `[]` is an array. `parent[1].val1` -> 3rd 'some data'. it's not possible to have a keyless data structure. either it's got an implicit numeric key (array), or it's got a string key (object).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realise there is a numeric key, I mean if I don't know the number of objects in the array, then how can I query them all without an explicit reference to a specific key? I'll update the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to match documents where a key contains an array of objects.

```
db.myCollection.find({ parent: { $elemMatch: { val1: someValue }}});
```

That's the mongo code, you'll have to convert it to PHP to access through the mongo driver.